# VBA single select on a Pivot Table field filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on my VBA code for a `PivotTable` field.

What I want to achieve is to only select `Acc Payable` in field `Group`. The following code can help me get what I want, but I'm considering whether there is a way to delete those `False` lines and make the code shorter?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Group")
        .PivotItems("Acc Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("FRG").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Non FinOps").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Semi Auto").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Acc Payable").Visible = True
    End With
        End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `For` loop, to iterate through the `PivotField` named "Group" `PivotItems`, and if the `PivotItem.Name = "Acc Payable"` then make it visible.

**Code**

```
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

For Each PvtItm In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Group").PivotItems
    If PvtItm.Name = "Acc Payable" Then
        PvtItm.Visible = True
    Else
        PvtItm.Visible = False
    End If
Next PvtItm
```

Comment: Thank you mate!This works perfectly on my code! Thanks